# Code block result as property value for a table

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm writing my thesis in Org→Latex. As well as the individual chapter files, I keep track of the overall structure and progress in a separate file. One thing I look at and have to report on is the number of pages written versus the intended length.

I can use `pdfinfo` to get the number of physical pages in the individual chapters and get this into the outline with a code block. And I can generate a "columnview" table that automatically updates from the chapter info in the outline. I'd like to find out how I could put the two together.

### Example

Hopefully this shows what I'm trying to do. In the real thing, there are obviously more like a dozen chapters.

```
#+TITLE: Thesis Outline
#+COLUMNS: %2ID %35ITEM %Target_Pages{+}

#+NAME: count-pdf-pages
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :exports none :var pdf-file=""
  (let
      ((pdf-file-info (shell-command-to-string (concat "pdfinfo " pdf-file))))
    (string-match "Pages:[[:blank:]]+\\([0-9]+\\)" pdf-file-info)
    (match-string 1 pdf-file-info)
    )
#+END_SRC

* Chapter outlines
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       outlines
  :END:
** 1. Introduction
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Target_Pages:    5
   :END:
 This is the introduction of the thesis. It currently has this many pages:
 #+NAME: intro-page-count
 #+CALL: count-pdf-pages("latex/intro-chapter.pdf")

* Page Allocation and Completion
#+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 1 :id outlines
| ID       | ITEM               | Target_Pages |
|----------+--------------------+--------------|
| outlines | * Chapter outlines |            5 |
|          | ** 1. Introduction |            5 |
#+END
```

### Question

What I would like to do is be able to use the return value of the `CALL` block for each chapter within the outline table at the end. However, having read through the relevant section of the manual a few times, I can't see whether it's possible to set a heading's property (say `Written_Pages`) to be the result of a code block.

Obviously, I'm also open to other org ways of approaching the problem of generating a table from the results of multiple code calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Org-mode properties can be set via elisp using `org-set-properties`.  For example, `(org-set-properties "Written_Pages" "5")` (note that the property value must be a string.  So just add an extra source block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :export none :results none :var p=intro-page-count
(org-set-property "Written_Pages" p)

#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Great, thank you, that works well. A nice refinement would be to know how to use a single-line `#+CALL:` block for each one. But these don't seem to get updated automatically with C-c C-v C-b, and also get messy having to pass the point about so that the property is set on the caller's header, not where the function is defined.